# SharePoint 2013 - Replace Master Page Header Color with Image

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, branding, header

I would like to replace the Master Page header background color with a banner/image.  Can this be done?  Do I make the change on the master page or in css?

[image: Replace this header color with an image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the CSS style below to achieve it, add the CSS style into  tag in master page.

```
<style type="text/css">
#suiteBarLeft{
    background-image:url('https://blog.fastaccounts.pk/wp-content/themes/fastaccounts/images/blog-banner-01.jpg');
    background-color:white !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you LZ_MSFT.

Answer (score 1):

Below script needs to be pasted inside the masterpage. Paste this above `</body>` tag in your masterpage.Refer [here](https://academy.bindtuning.com/customize-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-suite-bar/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var suitebar = $("#suiteBar");
     var branding = suitebar.find(".ms-core-brandingText");
     branding.html("<a href='/'><img src='/SiteAssets/yourimage.PNG' height='30px'></a>");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Sudheer.